# mp3 encoding and settings

Tags: mp3, cubase, encoding

For encoding mp3s I use the Fraunhofer codec that I think sounds the best. I found it in Nero program and I can record my cubase arrangements in audacity and save it as a wav file in audacity and encode it in Nero. Now it sounds good but I wonder if you can "approve" my process or suggest a better way to do it, perhaps I won't have to use all 3 programs? I should be able to script the mp3 encoding with AutoIt but that is more a programming problem than a sound engineering issue.

When I encode I select 256 bps stereo 41 khz sample rate. That setting is the lowest that sounds good. 128 or 192 is ok but 256 is good for me since I have quite a lot of drive space.

Are these settings and methods correct?

You can listen to my stuff at [www.soundcloud.com/niklasr](http://www.soundcloud.com/niklasr)

[image]
[image]

I suppose I can record from the mixer to DAT or from the mixer to the PC, so that I will get the sound of the Mackie mixer which is connected via USB to  the computer but I also failed to record digitally which could reduce the noise. I suppose that the noise is component noise from the plexgear soundcard in the analog recording through the soundcard and that I can try with a real soundcard, or without the computer and a hardware sequencer and not use a computer at all since the background noise is computer component noise.

Comment: Isn't the Fraunhofer MP3 encoder supplied with Cubase by default?

Comment: @EugeneS I would like to do it in Cubase but I don't know how to make an audio file in Cubase. When I do export audio it's not working and creates digital garbage. To create my sound files I play the song live in Cubase and record with audacity which can sound ok, then I use Nero to encode an mp3 and I would like to use Cubase for the entire process.

Comment: Well that's certainly not the way to do it. You should have an "Audio Mix-Down" under your File-->Export menu. There you should be able to select your File Format, Audio Engine Output and the related settings there.

Comment: Are you sure the below answer by @Stoyno answers your question here?

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. I'm going to try what you say which seems obvious.

Comment: It seems you are working with MIDI..? In this case you might have to route the VSTs you use to output bud as well.

Comment: @EugeneS Yes all tracks are MIDI. I have not learnt how to convert MIDI playback to mp3 other than recording it live in audacity. I don't know how to "route the VSTs" but I'm going to try everything. Can you be more specific what I select to route the VSTs? Can I put in more screenshots to sdisplay what's going on? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Unfortunately it's been some time since I have used Cubase last time and I'm afraid I won't be able to recall these settings right now. Try to Google for something like "cubase mixdown vst instruments".

Comment: I found this info but I'm still not sure how to perform the MIDI mixdown. I only have MIDI, no samples and no software synths. http://forum.recordingreview.com/f23/cubase-including-midi-tracks-audio-mixdown-16187/

Comment: Wait a moment.. You do hear something when you just hit play, right? If you do, there is something that producing these sounds, one of the VSTs you have. The main idea is to route everything to your output bus. MIDI by itself is just commands to a VST instruments, not a real audio. Unless real audio signal won't be routed to the output, it won't be downmixed. Try to understand where your MIDI channels are routed.

Comment: @EugeneS Yes, when I playback in Cubase the sounds are crystal clear and with absolutely no noise. The sounds come from my Roland 808, my Roland 909 and my Roland 303 and my Roland Juno 106, so I use external instruments controlled by MIDI. The only way I've succeeded in by playing to arrangement in Cubase and recording with audacity which is not the right method. I'd like to do it all in Cubase but it is so difficult since everything in Cubase can be on or off. Why must I do routing at all? Where and how do I do it? I don't understand how to route MIDI.

Comment: @EugeneS I can play in Cubase with no noise and my instruments are hardware synths and drummachines connected to a mackie mixer and I record the output from the Mackie mixer with the computer an daudacity. Somewhere the noise appears and I don't know how cubase audio mixdown can work since it won't record for instance the mixer settings. I could limit the noise in the mixer perhaps just by equalizing it out with the mixer. Are you sure that cubase audio mixdown is supposed to work for pure MIDI tracks that control hardware synths and hardware drum machines? I got Roland 106, 808 and 909.

Comment: You have to understand that there is a difference between MIDI and audio signals. When you have a MIDI channel in Cubase, it's just a set of commands transferred to some synth module. There are 2 options how to get a sound from these MIDI commands. First option is to route these commands to a VST instrument. Second option(and as far as I see this is the one you are using) is to attach an external module(in your case, your synth). So in that case, when your your external synth is the one who generates the audio, you should record the audio itself to cubase, not just MIDI commands.

Comment: Just connect your synth with simple audio cable to your PC audio interface (in whatever you do it) and record simple audio. Then you will be able to play it back and downmix that track in Cubase.

Comment: @EugeneS I think that's what I'm doing and that audio mixdown won't work since I'm getting the sounds from my hardware synths and hardware drum machines. I'm thinking of recording digitally from the Mackie mixer to reduce the noise but I might need a driver then for my computer to recognize the mixer. It seems I'll end up recording with audacity after all and that audio mixdown in cubase is not the option for a MIDI track that controls and external instrument?

Comment: I got a Mackie ProFX8 mixer with USB output that I can use to record the mixer since otherwise I don't think that I will get the sound from the Mackie mixer. So if I want the sound from the Mackie mixer I can't use cubase audio mixdown?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a Mix-Down directly in Cubase, without having to re-record your audio in Audacity and then encode it with Nero.

To export and audio file in Cubase, follow the following steps:

1. File
2. Export
3. Audio Mix-Down

There you should have all the options you need, like File Format, Audio Engine Output and all related settings.

*I'm also almost sure that the Fraunhofer encoder codec is included in Cubase by default.*

Comment: @909Niklas Pay attention that the only part of your track which is within the locators (small rectangles on your ruler) will be exported.

Comment: But the files cubase create have no sound. I can create a wav file or an mp3 file but they have no sound. The wav file was 12 MB which seems right but it has no sound.

Comment: @909Niklas Take a look here: http://www.steinberg.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=43957

Comment: I don't understand "the speaker button next to the record enable button". I updated the question with screenshots what's going on. The file that is created has no sound.

Comment: I delselected "record enable" for all tracks and still the mixdown file is silent.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are two types of encoder availible: [lossless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) and and [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_data_compression).

Studio applications should use lossy compression only as the last step to keep the audio quality high. In addition converting from one lossy file format to another lossy one e.g. from mp3 to aac results in a big quality loss. Even more than converting from a lossless to a lossy.

You should also export your wave file in Cubase instead of using Audacity. As the last step before distributing your audio files you can compress them lossy.

Which kpbs setting you use depends on what you want to do with it. In general you should try to use 320 CBR (constant bitrate) that VBR or lower CBR bitrates.

If you want to archive audio files and want to keep the quality high you should use lossless fileformats like flac. This results in a smaller file size than wav files but has still the same quality.

Comment: MP3 takes advantage of a perceptual limitation of human hearing and uses masking effect (among other processes) to reduce the size of an audio file. There is no such thing as lossless MP3 encoding.